# When manipulating different array indices in C/C++ with two threads, is synchronization needed?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose I have an array defined as follows:

```
volatile char v[2];
```

And I have two threads (denoted by A, B respectively) manipulating array `v`. If I ensure that A, B use different indices at any time, that is to say, if A is now manipulating `v[i]`, then B is either doing nothing, or manipulating `v[1-i]`. I wonder is synchronization needed for this situation?

I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940139/is-synchronization-needed-when-manipulating-different-arrayobject-array-indice), however I think it is limited in Java. The reason why I ask this question is that I have been struggling with a strange and rare bug in a large project for days, and up to now, the only reason I could come up with to explain the bug is that synchronization is needed for the above manipulation. (Since the bug is very rare, it is hard for me to prove whether my conjecture is true)

Edit: both reading and modifying are possible for `v`.

Comment: `If I ensure that A, B use different indices at any time`  How do you ensure this?  That in itself could be the problem, thus synchronization would need to be implemented.

Comment: I am sure I could ensure this (in fact, the procedure for selecting the indices for the two threads is synchronized) @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: What about side-effects?  The code to manipulate one value in the array could be causing side effects to occur in the other indexed value.  Since we don't have this code, that is the other conclusion one could come with as to why you're having an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a compiler bug or a hardware limitation.

Sometimes, when a less than 32-bit/64-bit variable is accesses from memory, the processor will read 32 bits, set the apprpriate 8 or 16 bits, then write back the whole register. That means it will read/write the adjacent memory as well, leading to a data race.

Solutions are

- use byte-access instructions. They may not be available for your processor or your compiler does not know to use them.
- pad your elements to avoid this kind of sharing. The compiler should do it automatically if your target platform does not support byte access. But in an array, this conflicts with the memory layout reqiurements.
- synchronize the whole structure

**C++03/C++11 debate**

In classic C++ it's up to you to avoid/mitigate this kind of behaviour. In C++11 this violates memry model requitements, as stated in other answers.

Comment: ``That means it will read/write the adjacent memory as well" is exactly what I am worried about. Thanks for your suggestions:)

Comment: "the processor will read 32 bits, set the apprpriate 8 or 16 bits, then write back the whole register." This behavior is forbidden in C++11! It would violate the memory model (see TCs answer)

Comment: But some compilers have bugs/some processors have limitations. Did you read the first sentence?

Comment: If you would compile for an arch that does not support 8 or 16 bit writes, then a conforming C++11 compiler would be obliged to insert padding into char arrays to comply to the memory model. Concerning compilerbugs: I think you should not adjust your code just because there *could* be a weird compilerbug. (Op is using vs so not C++11 anyway)

Comment: True. But in an array, that would break other things. Like casting from char[2] to uint16_t.

Comment: "A conforming C++ compiler" - the answer is all about a buggy/non-conforming compiler.

Comment: @gexicide arrays must be contiguous. A conforming implementation could, however, use a 32-bit `char`, or use appropriate atomic instructions so that the final observable behavior is the same (at some performance cost). Also, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#concurrencytable) says "N/A" for memory model, which apparently is [their way of saying "we are already doing this, nothing to do here"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

As far as the C++11 and C11 standards are concerned, your code is safe. C++11 §1.7 [intro.memory]/p2, irrelevant note omitted:

> A *memory location* is either an object of scalar type or a maximal
>   sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width. Two or more
>   threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory
>   locations without interfering with each other.

`char` is a integral type, which means it's an arithmetic type, which means that `volatile char` is a scalar type, so `v[0]` and `v[1]` are separate memory locations.

C11 has a similar definition in §3.14.

Before C++11 and C11, the language itself has no concept of threads, so you are left to the mercy of the particular implementation you are using.

Comment: That is helpful. I use vs2010 which does not support c11/c++11 standards well. Thank you:)

Comment: What if there is no `volatile` keyword? Will a `char` owned by one thread affected by the adjacent `char` owned by another thread?

Comment: It seems that you misunderstand the meaning of "A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width", which describes memory locations of bit-field variables in a struct/union/class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle synchronization only if you are accessing the same memory and modifying it. If you are only reading then also you don't need to take care about the synchronization.

As you are saying Each thread will access different indices then you don't require synchronization here. but you need to make sure that the two thread should not modify the same indice at the same time.